# TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**I'm getting this error, 'TypeError: dispatch is not a function' what am I doing wrong? I have read the documentation for redux but I can not see that I'm doing something wrong? (Beginner at redux) The fault is in the inputIsValid method**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { validatedAuthInput } from '../actions/index';

class AuthInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { inputValue: '' };
    }

    inputIsValid({ dispatch }, value) {
         dispatch(validatedAuthInput(this.props.type, value));

         this.validInput(this.props.type, value);
         return value.includes('@') && value.length > 4 ? 'success' : 'warning';
    }

    handleinput = event => {
        this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <FormGroup
                label={this.props.label}
                validationState={this.inputIsValid(this.state.inputValue)}>
                <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                    type={this.props.type}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    onChange={this.handleinput}
                />
                <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null)(AuthInput);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props is not automatically passed into that function so you need to do `this.props` inside the function instead. I will recommend you separate your actions from your component and pass a `mapDispatchToProps` object to `connect` [as described here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `connect` pattern, you'll be able to get at dispatch via: `this.props.dispatch`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `inputIsValid` function is trying to "destructure" the first argument and grab the `dispatch` property from there. This is wrong because then you're calling `this.inputIsValid` with just `this.state.inputValue` as an argument. But in any case you shouldn't be trying to receive `dispatch` as an argument in your function. Since this is an instance function (and you're component is connected), you have access to `dispatch` from `this.props.dispatch`.